# ROS Answers SE migration: Ros2 Stopwatch

Tags: ros2, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I want to implement a timer thats working like a stopwatch to check if my joy_node is continously sending messages.
Everytime it gets called the timer starts and if it doesnt get called again in a certain time I can start another event, for example to make sure the robot stops.
If the function gets called again (because the joy_node keeps sending messages) the timer just resets and the stop event doesnt get called.

Is there a timer function for doing this in ROS 2? (eloquent)

Sorry if the answer is obvious and I didnt find it.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352355/ros2-stopwatch/) by [pfedom](https://answers.ros.org/users/53854/pfedom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2020-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is commonly called a watchdog timer. I don't think that we have a specific timer to implement this.

I would also recommend that you look at the Deadline QoS documented here: https://design.ros2.org/articles/qos_deadline_liveliness_lifespan.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pfedom](https://answers.ros.org/users/53854/pfedom/) on 2020-05-16**:
Thank you!
I tried a bit with "Deadline" but ended up with a new question about how to use it properly.
https://answers.ros.org/question/352472/ros2-qos-deadline-usage/